# $\alpha \subset P(\Omega) : A, B\in \alpha \Rightarrow A\cup B \in \alpha, A \cap B \in \alpha$ algebra or semiring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, semiring

Is it easy to see if $\alpha $ is an algebra or a semiring? 
I have $\alpha \subset P(\Omega) $ ( $P(\Omega)$ powerset of $\Omega$ ) where $ A, B\in \alpha \Rightarrow A\cup B \in \alpha, A \cap B \in \alpha$. Is $\alpha$ an algebra or a semiring?

I know that if $\Omega \neq \varnothing $ and $\alpha \subset P(\Omega) $ then
$\alpha -$algebra $\Leftrightarrow $

i) $\Omega \in \alpha$ (or $\Omega , \varnothing \in \alpha$)

ii) $A \in \alpha \Rightarrow A^{c} \in \alpha $

iii) $A \in \alpha \Rightarrow A \cup B \in \alpha (\Leftarrow) A \cap B \in \alpha$

(or if $A_{i} \in \alpha ,i=1,2,...,n \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} \in \alpha$)

I know that $\alpha \subset P(\Omega) $ is called a semiring if:

i) $A, B \in \alpha \Rightarrow A \cap B \in \alpha$

ii) $A, B \in \alpha \Rightarrow$ there is a finite family $\begin{Bmatrix}
A_{j}, j=1,2,...,n
\end{Bmatrix}$ with $A_{j} \in \alpha$ for any $j$ and $A_{j} \cap A_{k} = \varnothing$ for any $ j \neq k$ :

$A-B = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}$

So, I don't have enough information to say that $\alpha$ is an algebra but do I have enough to say that $\alpha$ is a semiring?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = \{ \Omega \} $.

$\Omega, \Omega \in \alpha \Rightarrow \Omega \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \alpha$ and

$\Omega \cap \Omega = \Omega \in \alpha$ .

But $\varnothing = \Omega^{c} \notin \alpha$

So $\alpha$ is neither an algebra nor a semiring